# How to override parent's style in <i> tag

Tags: html, css, pseudo-class

I'm using the code below, so when the mouse is passed by the tag `i` (*TEST*)  the `i` won't get underline, but this is not working.

```css
div:hover {
  background-color: yellow;
  text-decoration: underline;
}
div .icon:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<h1>Welcome to My Homepage</h1>

<div>
  <h2>My name is Donald</h2>
  <p>I live in Duckburg.</p>
  <i class="icon icon-delete_enabled">TEST</i>
</div>

<p>My best friend is Mickey.</p>
```

Here is a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gL35t1bp/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need to set `display:inline-block` in `.icon`, also the `:hover` has to be done in the `div` parent

```css
div:hover {
  background-color: yellow;
  text-decoration: underline;
}

div:hover .icon {
  text-decoration: none;
  display:inline-block
}
```

```html
  <h1>Welcome to My Homepage</h1>

  <div>
    <h2>My name is Donald</h2>
    <p>I live in Duckburg.</p>
    <i class="icon icon-delete_enabled">TEST</i>
  </div>

  <p>My best friend is Mickey.</p>
```

Comment: Thanks! and why not display: inline-flex?

Comment: as long is not an inline element, go for it.

Comment: yes was marked but i was without of internet...sorry

Answer (score 0):

If I understand well, you want to underline the whole content on hover, but not the icon **only** when you point it?

```css
div:hover{
    background-color: yellow;
    text-decoration: underline;
}

div:hover .icon{
    text-decoration: underline;
}

div .icon{
    display:inline-block;
}

div .icon:hover{
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<h1>Welcome to My Homepage</h1>

<div>
  <h2>My name is Donald</h2>
  <p>I live in Duckburg.</p>
  <i class="icon icon-delete_enabled">TEST</i>
</div>

<p>My best friend is Mickey.</p>
```